# Changing light fixture inside hollow concrete wall

Tags: lighting, concrete, light-fixture, fixtures

So I decided to finally change my old ugly outside light fixture.

[image: Original light fixture]

Ran into a big problem. Everything inside was rusted through. The screws holding the light fixture metal bracket broke.

[image: inside light box]

I decided to try to remove the plastic box to see if I could somehow jerry-rig the box, so I decided to remove it.

I had to break the concrete around it a bit, but I got it out.

[image: light box hole]

I have a couple of new problems now. First things first. Since the new lamps have a circular disc type bracket I figured I could get some 3 inch 10-32 machine screws to hold the plate.

Not sure if this is the best way to secure it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using some nuts and washers to sandwich the circular plate and lift it up a bit since the box is about half in inch below the surface.

It is a little offset and I'm hoping that the lamp backing hides some of it.

Any suggestions on how I can improve this mess?

The other problem I have is that the backing isn't flat and when I put the box inside the wall there isn't anything to hold it in place. I'll have to mix some concrete and cover it up a bit before putting everything back in.

Comment: Why are you not getting new plastic box, rather then making new problems with your fix

Comment: I went to my local hardware store and they only had metal box.

Comment: Find another store, plastic is very common, or just use metal box, making sure you seal the light well along the wall to prevent water going in. You have a creative idea there, but it is difficult to execute.

Comment: Still have the other issue of how to attach the box to the hole in the wall.

Comment: I saw that problem...you will have to partially repair (fill) with stucco or mortar to create a surface so you can use screws with  anchors

Comment: Now that you have it out replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put some 10-24 3 inch stainless steel machine screws with some washers and nuts on the outlet box to secure the light fixture wall plate. I put some concrete in the hole and put some screws with some wire on the end of the outlet box to give it something for the concrete to hold on and strengthen it a bit. Painted around the hole.

[image]

Test fitted everything and made sure that the round plate was level.

[image]

Not a traditional fix, but seems sturdy enough and worked well.

[image]